# atom number change in pdb file with a specific line

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

[pdb file structure and I would like to change the number from 5427 and you could see that number in the same column are not in a sequential manner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTBhK.png)I am a newbie in Fortran. I would like to change the column numbering starting from the specific line which in my case is 5427. The numbers after this line in num(h) column is not in a sequential manner and I want it to be in sequence such as it would be 5428, 5429, etc. Could anyone please suggest me a way to do that?
I was trying to use if loop to compare them by comparing the num(h) value to 5427 and if it finds that I want it to change from the following line but my attempt was not successful.

```
program read_pdb
implicit none

!read the pdb file and fefine individual columns
character(len=4),Dimension(22986)::atom,restype
character(len=3),Dimension(22986)::resname 
integer,Dimension(22986)::num,atomnum
!integer(len=4),Dimension(22986)::atomnum
real,Dimension(22986)::x,y,z
character(len=11),Dimension(22986)::chamass
integer::h


!format for printing out the file
character(len=65),parameter::format="(A4,2X,I5,1X,A4,1X,A3,2X,I4,4X,F8.3,F8.3,F8.3,1X,A11)"

!read the file
open(unit=11, file="FVIII_v1.pdb", status="old", action="read")
! write the file
!open(unit=12,file="FVIII_v11.pdb",status="new",action="write")

do h=1,22986
read(11,format)atom(h),num(h),restype(h),resname(h),atomnum(h),x(h),y(h),z(h),chamass(h)
!write(*,format)atom(h),num(h),restype(h),resname(h),atomnum(h),x(h),y(h),z(h),chamass(h)
end do

! write only till 5426
do h=1,5426
write(*,format)atom(h),num(h),restype(h),resname(h),atomnum(h),x(h),y(h),z(h),chamass(h)
end do
! pick up from 5427 and start chaning the the number by adding 1 from the num

do h=5427,22986

write(*,format)atom(h),num(h)+1,restype(h),resname(h),atomnum(h),x(h),y(h),z(h),chamass(h)
end do
close(11)
end program read_pdb
```

Comment: How does the file format look like?

Comment: *but my attempt was not successful* What exactly happened? Error message? Wrong results? How did the results look like? Please create a small example with a smaller datafile with just a few atoms and share the datafile with us.

Comment: maybe you just want `h` instead of `num(h)+1` in that last write.

Comment: @agentp. Your answer solved my query.